# Как лучше сделать подсчет записей?

Tags: php, mysql

Как лучше реализовать подсчет записей (у категорий, различных фильтров), чтобы не было большой нагрузки? Использую PHP и MySQL.

На данный момент у меня 800 тыс.записей и подсчет идет напрямую из базы.

**список:**

1. Автомобили 240 500 тыс
2. Недвижимость 120 642 тыс
3. Услуги 299 003 тыс и
   т.д

Сначала подумал о кешировании данного списка, а потом вспомнил , что это меню еще и зависит от  фильтров и поисковых запросов.

Например: популярные доски объявлений. Как у них сделано.

Comment: Покажи структуру базы

Comment: У популярных досок объявлений не только MySQL есть.

Comment: я бы на вашем месте, делал бы промежуточное кеширование например в редисе или в чем то подобном или бы записывал в кеш постфактум кол.во записей.

Comment: По задаче - есть смысл посмотреть одним глазом в сторону OLAP.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от задачи.

Если допустима точность плюс-минус сколько то, то можно кешировать. Способов тьма.
Можно запихнуть в crontab задачу, которая будет раз в N минут собирать необходимую статистику и складывать в ту-же базу например.

Если нужно знать точно, то тут альтернатив запросам в БД как бы и нет. Используйте грамотный набор индексов.

Comment: Всего пяток фильтров по пять значений в каждом - и вот тебе более 7 тыс. статистик считать для кэширования даже в случае, если нет мультивыбора. При том что 99% посчитанного ни разу не потребуется. Не лучшее решение. Да и _грамотный набор индексов_ в этом случае весьма проблематично составить - или они будут пухлее, чем таблица с данными.